# How to correctly read a value from stdin into a variable

Tags: c++, string, input

I'm trying to read each player name using this method:

```
string Jogador::askname(){
    string aux;
    cout<<getname()<<" Insira o seu nome: ";
    cin.get();
    //getline(cin,aux);
    //gets(aux);
    cin.getline(aux,sizeof aux,'\n');
    //setname(aux);
    cout<<endl;
    return aux;
}
```

It works fine for the first call, but when I call it again, it cuts the first letter of the string. I've tried using `cin.get()` / `cin.ignore()`, nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `cin.get()` returns the first character of your stream, what did you think it did?

Comment: My teacher said it's used to get the '\n' contained in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to get `aux` from the keyboard.

`std::getline` takes a stream and a string. The contents of the stream up to the newline are put into the string.

Thus, you can write this:

```
std::string Jogador::askname() { 
    std::string aux;
    std::cout << " Insira o seu nome: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, aux);
    //this->name = aux; // This sets the name. Now you don't need `setname`
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I copied this code and now it completly ignores the input for the first call.It jumps to the second call. I call this method like this: j1.setname(j1.askname()); and then again for player 2 j2.setname(j2.askname()); .Now it jumps straight to player 2 (j2)

Comment: What "call" do you mean?

Comment: It would make more sense to set the name in `askname`.

Comment: setname() is used to access the private atributes of the class.In this case ,the string name atribute

Comment: I know what a setter is. You can call them whatever you want. Class methods have access to private variables.

Comment: @Ferro you probably have a `cin >> ` elsewhere in the program that you didn't clean up properly

Comment: Yes, it seems like the stream isn't being cleared, which is what `std::endl` does.

Comment: Probably ^^. I'll try moving "up" this method in the hierarchy of classes. The Player class is a derivative of the Person class which contains the private variable name.

Comment: It would be better if showed the whole code with all the member functions, as @erip said the stream must not be cleared

Comment: Also I tried `this->name = aux; ` but it's inaccessible. @Anirudh well the code it's a little extensive,I got so many `cin >>` that it would be bothersome ^^. But if that's the only way , well i'm screwed.

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste what I wrote? I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: @erip I did copy it.But as I said, it prints on screen both `cout << " Insira o seu nome: " << std::endl;`but only lets you insert the name for the second time the method is called.

Comment: @Ferro you need to clear the input stream after each time that you do `cin <<` and expect the person to have pressed Enter

Comment: Exactly,I just needed `fflush(stdin);` right after asking for input.Thanks everyone.